# How to unit test the class that reads Properties file

Tags: java, testing, junit, properties

I am trying to write the Junit test cases for the class that reads Properties file Here is my code:

```
public class PropertiesRetreiver {

    private String foo = "";
    private String foo1 = "";
    private static String PROPERTIES_PATH ="data.properties";

    public PropertiesRetreiver() throws IOException {

        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_PATH);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);

        foo = properties.getProperty("foo");
        foo1 = properties.getProperty("foo1");
    }

    public String getfoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public String getfoo1() {
        return foo1;
    }
}
```

Can anyone give me idea about test case scenario I can mock and test? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To start with, you have a hardcoded dependency on the file system, so it is going to be difficult to properly unit test that code. Could you consider passing the filename as a parameter to the constructor? That way you could at least try out different datasets in your unit test. As for what to test? Well, your code is simple, it only has one constructor and two getters, that's what you need to test.

Comment: I tried to add filepath in my constructor. But it doesn't get any value from properties file.

Comment: Are the properties environment dependent?  That is, one set for local, another for CI, another for production? Three test cases right there. Are the environments running the same technology stack? E.g. Mac OS/X local, Centos7 on the CI, Red Hat Linux in production?

Comment: the getmethods are sending null value to the junit test page

Comment: may be you don't need to mock at all, read it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300624/junit-how-to-test-a-method-that-read-properties-from-a-property-file

Answer (score 2):

Your class actually make 2 things : it loads a property file, and stores some specific properties.

For testing purpose, you could (should?) concentrate on one aspect at a time only, either by splitting these 2 roles in different class (a PropertiesLoader and PropertyStore for example) or at least allow for some injection in your class.

Removing unecessary code from the constructor is always a good idea if you want to properly test your classes :)

ex:

```
public class PropertiesRetreiver {

    private String foo = "";
    private String foo1 = "";
    private static String PROPERTIES_PATH ="data.properties";

    public PropertiesRetreiver() {
    }

    public void loadProperties() throws IOException {
        loadProperties(PROPERTIES_PATH);
    }
    public void loadProperties(String path) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(in);
        loadProperties(properties);
    }
    public void loadProperties(Properties properties) {
        foo = properties.getProperty("foo");
        foo1 = properties.getProperty("foo1");
    }

    public String getfoo() { return foo; }    
    public String getfoo1() { return foo1; }
}
```

This code will be much more easy to test since you can focus on each aspect of the properties load/retreival